# How to obtain an activity reference when created by an Intent

Tags: android

The activity is started here:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class), 2);
```

The ChatActivity starts then this method gets called and prints 2:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   System.out.println(requestCode);
}
```

Without changing the ChatActivity object, how may I obtain a reference to ChatActivity using Android API call(s)?

Comment: This doesn't sound like something android can do by default. What are you trying to do?

Comment: By design each Activity should be independent from any other. If it even is possible to get a Reference, it would be very difficult and should in any case be avoided. I can suggest a solution for your problem if you describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you're trying to get a reference to something that activity DID, then you want to investigate setResult() on the ChatActivity. You can attach info to the result by various putExtra() methods defined in the Intent class.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `ChatActivity` to pass information back to the activity that issued the intent, use extras. For example, in `ChatActivity` you might have:

```
Intent toIssuer = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key", value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, toIssuer);
```

And in the original activity's `onActivityResult`, you can get the extras back out with:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    System.out.println(data.getStringExtra("key"));
}
```